# newsstand icon change with issues

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios5

Does anybody knows how to change icon on newsstand application every time I add new issues. That icon should be cover page of magazine. 
I saw some magazines that they have that option so need some tutorial or data about it.
Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the Apple WWDC Videos from 2011. There is one about building a newsstand app including sample code in the pdf version.

http://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/

Watchlink: https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/includes/building-newsstand-apps.html#building-newsstand-apps

Slides: https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2011/adc_on_itunes__wwdc11_sessions__pdf/504_building_newsstand_apps.pdf

Answer (score 0):

The gist of Bastian’s answer, repeated for people who don’t have access to the dev center.

Use:

```
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNewsstandIconImage:yourImage];
```